# Unable to press UIButton underneath NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I have an app where there is a navigation controller which can have navigation child. I have to put a UIButton where the navigation bar is normally.

The UIButton is connected to targets:

```
for button in arrayOfButtons {
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTouchUpInsideP3), for: [.touchUpInside])
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTouchInsideBoundsP3), for: [.touchDown, .touchDragEnter])
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonDraggedOutOfBoundsP3), for: [.touchDragExit, .touchCancel]) //there is definitly combining that cud be done here...
}
```

And basically I can't simply hide the navigationBar as I use it for sizing/autolayout, so what I try to do is: (this code is in the ViewDidLoad of the child navigation controller)

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

To remove its UI and have it invisible up there, this part works... however, the issue is that I still cannot press anything in the navigationBar area... even though I do `isUserInteractionEnabled = false`.

How can I fix this!? So that I can tap a UIButton underneath(?) or rather where the navigationBar is located??

Haven't seen a SO question that has solved this for me :/

Comment: The navigation bar is still on top of the view. Blocking the views below it from being touched. User interaction just prevents that view from trigging events and doesn’t allow for pass though events.

Comment: @StonedStudio I see... do you have any ideas on how I can get those UIButtons to be able to be tapped then?

Comment: I would try setting .isHidden = true - instead of trying to hide it with the other commands. .isHidden should take care of all of that while sending firstResponder status to the next available view. - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622585-ishidden

Comment: @StonedStudio well the issue with doing that is that then I cannot use the navigationBar as a autolayout reference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for anyone that wants to know:

@StonedStudio was right, I ended up just hiding the navigation bar and instead I simply created a view with the bounds height of the navigationBar anchored to the top of the view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor and that way it takes the shape of the would be navigation bar while allowing the tap as well! :)